# What react-native library available for encrypting/decrypting data by public/private keys

Tags: public-key-encryption, cryptojs

Can someone suggest a react-native lib for encrypting/decrypting data using public/private keypair? I'm currently using ethers.js for generating keypair and wanting to encrypt files using generated public key. I've tried 'crypto-js', 'react-native-crypto-js' but none of them work. The error is below:

"this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved..."

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with tweetnacl-js which seems OK